# Create group within one UNIQUE VALUE in teradata

Tags: teradata

## SESSION_ID---STATUS---Desired---

1C1A1111111---Start---Trip1---

1C1A1111111---?---Trip1---

1C1A1111111---?---Trip1---

1C1A1111111---?---Trip1---

1C1A1111111---?---Trip1---

1C1A1111111---Stop---Trip1---

1C1A1111111---?------

1C1A1111111---?------

1C1A1111111---?------

1C1A1111111---?------

1C1A1111111---Start---Trip2---

1C1A1111111---?---Trip2---

1C1A1111111---?---Trip2---

1C1A1111111---?---Trip2---

1C1A1111111---?---Trip2---

1C1A1111111---?---Trip2---

1C1A1111111---?---Trip2---

1C1A1111111---?---Trip2---

1C1A1111111---Stop---Trip2---

Comment: Data have two columns i need to create TRIP1 & TRIP2 based on start and stop so the row between start and stop is one trip

Comment: I'm assuming you have a timestamp column?

Comment: Yes I do have timestamp column

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE    -- check if current row is between start and stop
   WHEN Last_Value(status IGNORE NULLS)
        Over (PARTITION BY session_id
              ORDER BY ts
              ROWS  Unbounded Preceding ) = 'start'
     OR status = 'stop'

        -- increase trip number whenever status = 'start'
   THEN Sum(CASE WHEN status = 'start' THEN 1 END)
        Over (PARTITION BY session_id
              ORDER BY ts
              ROWS Unbounded Preceding) 
END
```